Is there a non-verbose way to disable multiple error codes via a mypy command?
If I want to disable multiple error codes in mypy (without modifying any config files or adding comments to .py files), I can do the following:
mypy --disable-error-code truthy-function --disable-error-code no-redef .

However, this can easily become verbose when the number of error codes you want to disable increases. Is there some way to accomplish the same behaviour without needing to repeat the --disable-error-code flag?
In this answer, there's a way to do what I want, except for the fact that it's as a comment in a .py file rather than as a standalone command.

Why don't you want to use config files? You can have multiple configuration files, and select which one you actually want to use (say, foo) for a particular run with mypy --config-file foo.
